# dropdown not updated from computed observable

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have the following computed observable:

```
        self.getMovieDates = ko.computed(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Utilities/UpdateTimesDropdown',
                data: { apiId: self.movieSelectedValue(), locationId: self.theatreSelectedValue() },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.showtimes);
                    return data.showtimes;
                }
            });
        }, self);
```

The html looks like this:

```
    <select id="DateDD" data-bind="options: getMovieDates,
                            optionsText: 'title',
                            optionsValue: 'id',
                            optionsCaption: 'Select Showdate',
                            value: dateSelected"></select>
```

I can see in firebug that the ajax request is being made, I there are values being received. "console.log(data.showtimes)" looks like this:

```
 [Object { id="3/24/2015", title="Today (Tue, Mar 24, 2015)"}, Object { id="3/25/2015", title="Tomorrow (Wed, Mar 25, 2015)"}, Object { id="3/26/2015", title="Thu, Mar 26, 2015"}]
```

Unfortunately, the drop down just does not get populated and I am running low on ideas, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success function is returning data to jquery internals that are calling it, not to the outer function which you're passing to the computed.

You have to make an observable and then set it in your success function. You then use your observable in the view model, not your computed.

EDIT: your own helpful link: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Asynchronous-Dependent-Observables :)

Comment: Good find, however, when I made a new observable, replaced getMovieDates with it in html, in my 'success' assigned to that observable, I get the same result :/

Comment: In a meeting, give me a couple minutes and I'll give you a pattern.  Or if you can't wait just google for "async computed" or something similar.  Basically you have to make an observable and then set it in your success function.  You then use your observable in the view model, not your computed

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I figured it out! This link is also helpful: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Asynchronous-Dependent-Observables